# Android touchpaint API

Tags: android

I am playing around with the touchpaint api, i was wondering if anyone could point to some code that could save a drawing to the sd card.

Answer (score 0):

From sensors/src/aexp/sensors/SensorMonitor.java found in Android SDK's samples:

This is how you create the file:

```
    private PrintWriter captureFile;

    File captureFileName = new File( "/sdcard", "capture.csv" );
        captureStateText = "Capture: "+captureFileName.getAbsolutePath();
        try {
            captureFile = new PrintWriter( new FileWriter( captureFileName, false ) );
        } catch( IOException ex ) {
            Log.e( LOG_TAG, ex.getMessage(), ex );
            captureStateText = "Capture: "+ex.getMessage();
        }
```

This is how you write to the file:

```
    if( captureFile != null ) {
            for( int i = 0 ; i < sensorEvent.values.length ; ++i ) {
                if( i > 0 )
                    captureFile.print( "," );
                captureFile.print( Float.toString( sensorEvent.values[i] ) );
            }
            captureFile.println();
    }
}
```

And finally you close the file:

```
        captureFile.close();
```